# Github: bind source code downloaded from github for working on it

Tags: git, github, configuration-management

-- updated question --

I have a repository having 1.21 GB size. So `git clone` isn't working for me. so, I downloaded source code zip from github.

I made some changes, and now I want to commit and push those changes to github repository.

-- updated question --

Is it possible?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What exactly did you download? What do you want to do with it? What do you want git to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the only way that you can send something to a git repository is to actually have a clone with changes. You will either need to send a patch to someone, or clone the repository yourself and apply the changes.